# R raster package plot() producing monochrome images

Tags: r, plot, raster, monochrome

I would like to get monochrome images using plot function. But it keeps on producing color images. I even had monochrome images that i plotted using plot function and i got them in some weird green and orange color. How can i make plot function provide monochrome images? I tried to read about getValues function but found it difficult to understand as i am not from image analysis background. It seems that getBlocks() function returns monochrome images. But is there a way to get monochrome images using just plot function?

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))
plot(r)
#even below lines produce a yellow color image. i thought that they will produce a black or white square
r <- raster(matrix(rep(0,100), 10))
plot(r)
```

Comment: The image you produce is monochrome, since it includes only yellow. You probably mean grayscale.

Comment: you comment makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for gray scale vector of colors, you can use `gray.scale()` for the `col` argument in `plot()`:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(rnorm(100), 10))
plot(r, col = gray.colors(10, start = 0.3, end = 0.9, gamma = 2.2, alpha = NULL))
```

You were getting the greens from `plot()` because the default for `col` use

```
rev(terrain.colors(255))
```

Comment: any idea how i can plot my image in original colors (instead of green and yellow)?